# How to define security label on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I think SECURITY LABEL command. But I don't understand how to define security label.
I try:

```
SECURITY LABEL;
```

and

```
SECURITY LABEL FOR selinux;
```

and

```
SECURITY LABEL FOR selinux ON TABLE mytable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-security-label.html) this is the correct usage of SECURITY LABEL

```
SECURITY LABEL FOR selinux ON TABLE mytable IS 'system_u:object_r:sepgsql_table_t:s0';
```

Note for this restriction also:

> register_label_provider is not an SQL function; it can only be called from C code loaded into the backend.